# Firefox developer edition insecure connection all the time

Tags: macos, https, trusted-root-certificates, firefox-developer-edition

Just installed FDE at my work, but I get the following message when trying to visit youtube.com, google.com and sites:

> Your connection is not secure
>
> The owner of www.youtube.com has configured their website improperly.
>   To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox Developer
>   Edition has not connected to this website.
>
> This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that
>   Firefox Developer Edition only connect to it securely. As a result, it
>   is not possible to add an exception for this certificate.

What the hell is this? How can I fix it?

Currently my FDE network settings are "No proxy", I have not touched anything about certificates or stuff in the security tab.

Hope you guys can help, since I like the browser.. but maybe not for long.

Comment: Information on the certificate Firefox thinks YouTube is using would be helpful.

Comment: found the solution gonna post it in 2 secs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution.

The issue was "AVAST Mac Security", as described in this article: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1032509

The problem was caused by the following (copy paste from the link above):

> in order to be able to decrypt and inspect your communications, the software needs to present a fake certificate to Firefox

So when i uninstalled AVAST and rebooted my laptop, everything was fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Duck Duck Go, Start page, Google almost all the search engines except for Amazon & eBay, had the same message. I found script on the browser settings? Deleted it and the problem went away? The file was strange as was the script. It looks like some one has gone through a bit of trouble to write this as it effected so many browsers on a Linux system, Even bypassing the anti virus search clam Win and another I can not recall. The script actually had the name of the anti virus on it with commands to ignore or not show a positive reading.

Comment: What script are you referring to? Your answer really need this information to be of any use.